# Wordpress WSOD on install

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wsod

I'm having some trouble with a brand new WP-install. I'm trying to install it on a clients host. There was already an installation of WP when i began my installation. I asked the client about it and was tolk i could remove it, it was just for test from their side. I saved it however and also copied the db and stuff.

Then, i removed all files from the FTP, i removed all the tables in the DB and all that jazz.
Then, i took a brand new downloaded version of WP and uploaded it. I set all the proper values in wp-config.php and then launched the site and got a white screen of death.

I removed the wp-config.php and i got the "There's no wp-config"-stuff. I tried to alter the file and and even used the wisard, either way i got a WSOD or a WP-error. I get redirected to "wp-admin/install.php" but that's it. 
In the install.php I started to echo stuff to see where the crash were. 
It seems that it crashed on this line:

```
require_once( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/wp-load.php' );
```

Then, i tried to set the define('WP_HOME', '') and d define('WP_SITEURL', '') to the actual URL. 
I tried even to take the old sites .htaccess file, but it gave me nothing.
Then i started to google and found nothing.

After this, i gave up and installed all the old tables the client had there before for testing, and then uploaded the old site. Still a WSOD.

Anybody who knows what's going on here?

Comment: Any chances to see a log file or something like that? Is the server showing php error messages?

Comment: Yea, i started to look in the log, and there are tons or redeclarations. First i had a bunch of them in wp-includes/rewrite.php and i commented them out, then i got an redeclaration error in wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php and realized the file was repeating itself... like 
/** bla blah <?php stuff and in the middle of the file it repeats itself with this text again... the file does not look like this on localhost. something is happening when i upload?

Comment: The WSOD is very much likely a fatal PHP error. Can you access the php  configuration of the server?

Comment: Is your htaccess file set to the correct path for your site installation?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as i mentioned in the comment, the problem was a bunch of redeclarations...

Something went really bad when the files were transfered, files got really bad.

If a file looked like this:

```
<?php
/* BLA BLA INFO */
function a_function()
{ //something }
```

the file could look like this when it was uploaded:

```
<?php
/* BLA BLA INFO */
function a_function()
{ //something }
<?php
/* BLA BLA INFO */
function a_function()
{ //something }
```

This made the redeclarations in some files, not all of them, just random files.
The host got the same trouble when they tested, so something is really bad over there.

At least, now i know why the reason for the WSOD :)